# Can I lookup a software version number which is bundled with a specific CentOS version without installing CentOS?

Tags: centos, package-management, versioning

Is there a website where I can enter a software package (for example Apache) and select a CentOS version number and get the version number of Apache which comes with the selected CentOS distribution?

Comment: are you saying you don't have CentOS installed or you don't want to install the package before finding out the version? Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: @MarkFisher I don't have anything installed. I need it to check dependencies I can list for the production environment. I make that clear in the headline.

Comment: You do now, but the original headline said "it", hence my question. I've added a suggestion below.

Comment: Please keep in mind that for almost every package the software version remains the same for the whole life-cycle of major release, only the patch level should change. For instance requiring  CentOS 6.4 is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to an [rpm search site like this one](http://rpm.pbone.net/), click Search / Advanced Search and then you can tick the distributions you wish to query against.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can browse the CentOS software repositories which contain only the software distributed by CentOS.

**CentOS 5**:

- http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/
- http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/updates/x86_64/RPMS/

**CentOS 6**:

- http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6/os/x86_64/Packages/
- http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/

**CentOS 7** :

- http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/os/x86_64/Packages/
- http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/

If you just need the major revision number (e.g. php53 -> php 5.3) then you need only look at the RPMs under the "os" directory.  If you need minor revision numbers (updates, e.g. php53-5.3.3-24) then also look at the RPMs under the "updates" directory.